# Air leaking from breakers on air handler

Tags: hvac

This is the air handler in my attic.  The attic is over 90 degrees (it is sealed, there is spray foam on roof)
There is a lot of air leaking, most notable from around the breaker[image: breaker panel leaking]
[image: temperature in area]

How do I stop the air from leaking?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  "Thoughts" is not a reasonable question around here.  Is there something that you want to know or want to do that you need help with?

Comment: I took the "Thoughts?" question out and put in the question I think you're really asking. If this isn't your desired question, please edit and clarify your question to an answerable one per this site's guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

A "lot" of air may not be so much compared to what the unit is delivering to its intended destination; think volume comparison.  That said, use additional foam to seal holes between non-moving parts, but minimally over electrical cables carrying significant current (mains vs thermostat/controls).

I have an electric furnace with breakers mounted on the front of the housing like yours that has a soft plastic (vinyl?) cover that keeps treated air in and water out, while still allowing manipulation of the breakers.  They look like [this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=circuit%20breaker%20cover%20guard&atb=v296-1&iax=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fzago.com%2Fimages%2Fproducts%2FCircuitBreakerCoversAndBoots-L.jpg&ia=images) (I'm sorry I don't have a photo of mine; it's in a rental unit.). If you rarely have to flip the breakers, you could simply cover them with plastic cut from a bag, taped to the surrounding surface.

Answer (score 2):

The front panel around the breakers appears to be bent, and in on place bent extensively, so it is not sealing closely against the breakers. See the red arrows:

[image: arrows at bent places in panel]

Bend the panel back to flat, and it will probably seal against the breakers better.

If lots of air is coming into the area behind the breakers, there may be a missing panel inside the unit behind the panel covering the breakers. Try looking for missing panels that should cover the heated air output.